# check if value is the same in while loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I'm converting a csv file to xml using the following function:

I want to repeat the same action if $records[$row] value is the same as the previous time that it looped through.  How can I accomplish this?

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $num = count($data);
  $records[] = $data;

  $stringData .= '<PayTo PTPayeeID="' . $records[$row][2];

  // if the value of $records[$row][2] is the same I want to repeat an action.
  echo "<div id=\"row\"><div id=\"num\">" .$row. "</div>";
  $row++;

  for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
     if ($c != 1) {
       echo "<div class=\"field\">" . $data[$c] . "</div>";
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use single quotes and concatenation, or double quotes and variable interpolation. Things will be a lot cleaner: `'<div id="row">' . $row . '</div>'` or `"<div id=\"num\">$row</div>"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, to compare a row with the previous one, store the previous row's value in a variable.
Make sure to assign the variable with a value that won't occur as a real value in your data.

```
$prevValue = NULL;
while(condition) {
 if ($curValue == $prevValue) {
  .
  . do stuff
  .
 }
 $prevValue = $curValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Before the while loop do:

```
$prevRow2 = '';
```

Then you can compare:

```
if ($records[$row][2] == $prevRow2) {
    // it's the same as the last time!
}
```

After using `$records[$row][2]`, simply copy it to `$prevRow2` before continuing the while loop.

(If it's possible that `$records[$row][2]` can be an empty string and you don't want it to match the first iteration, create a `$firstTime` boolean to check for this.)

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful - but its still not the way I need it to be.  I need it to print the current record $records[$row][2] once and then if the next time it loops through its the same, then it should repeat that action same action.

Comment: @MG1: I'm merely showing you how to *detect* if it's the same as last time. What do you mean by "action"?

Comment: Here is an example:                                                                                                           while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$num = count($data);
$records[] = $data; 
$stringData .= 'Print Once';
if ($records[$row][2] == $prevRow2) {
$stringData .= 'Keep reprinting with the new data that's within $records[$row][2]';
 }$prevRow2 = $records[$row][2];
  $row++;
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
if ($c != 1) { 
           echo $data[$c];
} 
}
    }
 $stringData .= '</ns0:TPDocXML>';
    fclose($handle);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($records)>1&&$records[count($records)-1]===$records[count($records)-2]) {
  //do something
}
```